# Difference between by and with

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between with and by in sentences below?

> You can buy better one by an extra payment of $400.
>
> You can buy better one with an extra payment of $400.

When I use these preposition I know what “with” means here. But I couldn’t understand what “by” means . Is it used like “with” or “by making extra payment”?

Comment: [an extra $400 payment = better here]

Comment: @Lambie Google ngrams says "payment of $100" is used more frequently than "$100 payment". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%24100+payment%2Cpayment+of+%24100&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%24%20100%20payment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpayment%20of%20%24%20100%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In this context (with _buy_) neither _by_ nor _with_ would be a complement of the verb, so they both have their ordinary meaning, that is essentially the same: "by means of". As Paul Tannenbaum points out, _buy_ can take a complement phrase for the price with _for_, so that is a better choice than either here.

Comment: @CJDennis Google ngrams does not "say anything". It reproduces written texts. Anyway, the entire thing needs rewriting. "You can buy **a** better one by paying an extra $400. Now, it's correct.

Comment: @Lambie Please show me an anti-definition that says "say" can't be used that way.

Answer (score 1):

*By* would mean, "by making."

(And you probably mean "**a** better one.")

(And a better way to put it is "for an additional payment of.")

Comment: Yes I missed. Does both sentence mean the same ? I mean can use also “with”?

Comment: I'd advise against your first. Your second is OK, but far more natural sounding is any of, "for an additional payment of $400," "for another $400," or "for $400 more."